# how to make a quantity change function for a shopping cart?

Tags: javascript, html

Here is a link to my application https://connorlewis128.github.io/ShoppingPage/Dist/product.html

when you click on the cart in the top right after adding something to the cart you will be brought to that cart page
here is my current attempt at the quantity change function but i am pretty stuck

```
// quantity change
function quantityChange() {
  if (document.querySelector("btn-plus")) {
    products.inCart = products.inCart + 1;
  } else if (document.querySelector("btn-minus")) {
    products.inCart = products.inCart - 1;
  }
}
```

let me know if more information or code is needed

Comment: Are you intending for these actions to happen on click? If so `if(document.querySelector('btn-plus'))` is only verifying the element exists. You would have to `document.querySelector(...).addEventListener('click', (event) => { });`. Also do you mean to have `btn-plus` there? If it's an ID it should be `#btn-plus`.

Comment: yes i do intend to have these happen on click, and it would `.btn-plus` as its a class

Comment: @AlexD what would the add event listener code look like i tried to implement that early but was getting undefined / null errors.

Comment: The undefined/null errors are probably due to the query selector. If the browser is unable to find an element matching the selector, it will return undefined. You'll get something like "unable to access property addEventListener of undefined" in that case. The other case would be that you're trying to query the element before it gets created. If you're able to provide a more complete example of the problem (maybe in codesandbox.io or another like it) I can help further.

Comment: @AlexD i havent used code sandbox.io but uploaded the files to one here is the link https://codesandbox.io/s/wizardly-waterfall-jqcn5

Comment: `quantityChange(1)` or `quantityChange(-1)` and `function quantityChange(amt) { products.inCart += amt; }`

Comment: The codesandbox helps. I think I've identified an issue, going to use an answer though so I have more space to type and use examples.

Comment: @AlexD ok i await your answer thanks again for your help

Comment: @connorlewis128 I have taken the code from Github . . . the code has a lot of bugs! I am trying to fix them!

Comment: And when you are using node . . . y have u not divided the code!

Comment: @connorlewis128 I have added the answer! Check it out!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do like this,

#### **Step 1:** Change the `displayCart` function to:

```js
function displayCart() {
  let cartItems = localStorage.getItem("productsInCart");
  cartItems = JSON.parse(cartItems);
  console.log(cartItems);
  let cartContainer = document.querySelector(".products");
  let cartCost = localStorage.getItem("totalCost");

  if (cartItems && cartContainer) {
    cartContainer.innerHTML = "";
    Object.values(cartItems).map((products) => {
      cartContainer.innerHTML += `
      <div class="products">
        <span>${products.name}</span>
        <img src="${products.Tag}" />
        <i class="btn-remove fas fa-times-circle"></i>
        <div class="productPrice">$${products.price}</div>
        <div class="productQuantity">
          <span class="btn-minus"><i class="fas fa-arrow-alt-circle-left"></i></span>
          <span class="curItems">${products.inCart}</span>
          <span class="btn-plus"><i class="fas fa-arrow-alt-circle-right"></i></span>
        </div>
        <div class="Total">$${products.price * products.inCart}</div>
      </div>
      `;
    });

    cartContainer.innerHTML += `
      <section class="basketTotalContainer">
      <h4 class="basketTotalTitle">
          Basket Total:
      </h4>
      <h4 class="BasketTotal">
          $${cartCost}.00
      </h4>
      </section>`;
  }
}
```

---

#### **Step 2:** Change the `quantityChange` function to:

```js
function quantityChange() {
  const plusBtnNew = document.querySelector(".btn-plus");
  const minusBtnNew = document.querySelector(".btn-minus");
  const curItems = document.querySelector(".curItems");

  plusBtnNew.addEventListener("click", () => {
    const total = Number(localStorage.getItem("cartNumbers"));
    localStorage.setItem("cartNumbers", total + 1);
    curItems.textContent = total + 1;
  });

  minusBtnNew.addEventListener("click", () => {
    const total = Number(localStorage.getItem("cartNumbers"));
    localStorage.setItem("cartNumbers", total - 1);
    curItems.textContent = total - 1;
  });
}
```

---

#### Final `store.js` code:

```js
const sizeBtn = document.querySelector(".btn-group1");

const showcase = document.querySelector(".showcase");

let carts = document.querySelectorAll("#add-to-cart");
let favorites = document.querySelectorAll("#favorite");
console.log(favorites);
let products = [
  {
    name: "ZIPPERED HOODED SWEATSHIRT",
    Tag:
      "https://connorlewis128.github.io/ShoppingPage/Dist/images/new%20product/black%20jacket/front.webp",
    price: 50.0,
    inCart: 0,
  },
];

// add to cart
for (let i = 0; i < carts.length; i++) {
  carts[i].addEventListener("click", () => {
    cartNumbers(products[i]);
    totalCost(products[i]);
  });
}

function onLoadCartNumbers() {
  let productNumbers = localStorage.getItem("cartNumbers");

  if (productNumbers) {
    document.querySelector("span .navbarCart").textContent = productNumbers;
  }
}

// Number of items added to cart
function cartNumbers(products) {
  let productNumbers = localStorage.getItem("cartNumbers");
  productNumbers = parseInt(productNumbers);
  if (productNumbers) {
    localStorage.setItem("cartNumbers", productNumbers + 1);
    document.querySelector("span .navbarCart").textContent = productNumbers + 1;
  } else {
    localStorage.setItem("cartNumbers", 1);
    document.querySelector("span .navbarCart").textContent = 1;
  }

  setItems(products);
}
// favorites
for (let i = 0; i < favorites.length; i++) {
  favorites[i].addEventListener("click", () => {
    favItems(products[i]);
    totalCost(products[i]);
  });
}

function onLoadfavNumbers() {
  let favNumbers = localStorage.getItem("favItems");

  if (favNumbers) {
    document.querySelector("span .favoritesCount").textContent = favNumbers;
  }
}

// number of favorites added
function favItems(products) {
  let favNumbers = localStorage.getItem("favItems");
  favNumbers = parseInt(favNumbers);
  if (favNumbers) {
    localStorage.setItem("favItems", favNumbers + 1);
    console.log(favNumbers);
    document.querySelector("span .favoritesCount").textContent = favNumbers + 1;
  } else {
    localStorage.setItem("favItems", 1);
    document.querySelector("span .favoritesCount").textContent = 1;
  }

  setItems(products);
}

function setItems(products) {
  let cartItems = localStorage.getItem("productsInCart");
  cartItems = JSON.parse(cartItems);

  if (cartItems != null) {
    if (cartItems[products.Tag] == undefined) {
      cartItems = {
        ...cartItems,
        [products.Tag]: products,
      };
    }
    cartItems[products.Tag].inCart += 1;
  } else {
    products.inCart = 1;
    cartItems = {
      [products.Tag]: products,
    };
  }
  localStorage.setItem("productsInCart", JSON.stringify(cartItems));
}
function totalCost(products) {
  let cartCost = localStorage.getItem("totalCost");
  if (cartCost != null) {
    cartCost = parseFloat(cartCost);
    localStorage.setItem("totalCost", cartCost + products.price);
  } else {
    localStorage.setItem("totalCost", products.price);
  }
}

// display cart
function displayCart() {
  let cartItems = localStorage.getItem("productsInCart");
  cartItems = JSON.parse(cartItems);
  console.log(cartItems);
  let cartContainer = document.querySelector(".products");
  let cartCost = localStorage.getItem("totalCost");

  if (cartItems && cartContainer) {
    cartContainer.innerHTML = "";
    Object.values(cartItems).map((products) => {
      cartContainer.innerHTML += `
      <div class="products">
        <span>${products.name}</span>
        <img src="${products.Tag}" />
        <i class="btn-remove fas fa-times-circle"></i>
        <div class="productPrice">$${products.price}</div>
        <div class="productQuantity">
          <span class="btn-minus"><i class="fas fa-arrow-alt-circle-left"></i></span>
          <span class="curItems">${products.inCart}</span>
          <span class="btn-plus"><i class="fas fa-arrow-alt-circle-right"></i></span>
        </div>
        <div class="Total">$${products.price * products.inCart}</div>
      </div>
      `;
    });

    cartContainer.innerHTML += `
      <section class="basketTotalContainer">
      <h4 class="basketTotalTitle">
          Basket Total:
      </h4>
      <h4 class="BasketTotal">
          $${cartCost}.00
      </h4>
      </section>`;
  }
}

function removeItem() {
  let removeItem = document.getElementsByClassName("btn-remove");
  console.log(removeItem);
  for (let i = 0; i < removeItem.length; i++) {
    let button = removeItem[i];
    button.addEventListener("click", function (event) {
      console.log("clicked");
      let removeItem = event.target;
      removeItem.parentElement.remove();
    });
  }
}

// color change

function colorChange() {
  showcase.style.animation =
    document.querySelector('input[name="colorradio"]:checked').value +
    " 6s infinite";
}

// quantity change
function quantityChange() {
  const plusBtnNew = document.querySelector(".btn-plus");
  const minusBtnNew = document.querySelector(".btn-minus");
  const curItems = document.querySelector(".curItems");

  plusBtnNew.addEventListener("click", () => {
    const total = Number(localStorage.getItem("cartNumbers"));
    localStorage.setItem("cartNumbers", total + 1);
    curItems.textContent = total + 1;
  });

  minusBtnNew.addEventListener("click", () => {
    const total = Number(localStorage.getItem("cartNumbers"));
    localStorage.setItem("cartNumbers", total - 1);
    curItems.textContent = total - 1;
  });
}

onLoadCartNumbers();
onLoadfavNumbers();
displayCart();
removeItem();

quantityChange();
```

Comment: Thank you the quantity now updates I appreciate your time and effort! I am going to attempt to update the product and cart totals on my own for now but will comment if i have questions. sorry for the bugs I am quite new to JS.

Comment: @connorlewis128 No problem ✌ . . . also there is good need to store the `total cost` of items . . . you can just multiply it where every yo need!

Comment: You can ask me if you have any doubts on discord **Manas Khandelwal#5460**, if you want ✌!

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is in your code you have `document.getElementsByClassName('.btn-plus')`, so for `getElementsByClassName` you don't want the ".", but in `querySelector` you do.

[image]

[image]

As far as updating the quantity with the event listener, you'll want to do something like the following:

1. I added an `id` attribute of "quantity" to your `span` containing `product.inCart`. This is important so we can get a reference to this `span` element so we can update it's `innerText` property.
   [image]
2. I added the code like so and verify it worked on my machine:
   [image]

However, the code you'll want to add here will be a little different because through Chrome DevTools I don't have access to your products object.
You'll want something like this

```js
document.querySelector('.btn-plus').addEventListener('click', () => {
    const quantityText = document.querySelector('#quantity');
    quantityText.innerText = `${products.inCart++}`;
});
```

Comment: Yeah yours would. He just needs to either remove the "." or change the function to querySelector

Comment: But he mentioned that it has not worked . . .you solution is useless!

Comment: This mistake was visible in the code he provided above!

Comment: The code he provided in the codesandbox differs from the code he provided in the question. In the question he uses querySelector, but in the code he uses getElementsByClassName.

Comment: And yes, I pointed this out in the comments on the original question 40+ minutes ago, but I think there is confusion on the difference between `getElementsByClassName` and `querySelector` as mentioned.

Comment: should i use querry selector or get element by class name

Comment: @AlexD  and  @ManasKhandelwal  `const plusBtnNew = document.querySelector(".btn-plus");
const minusBtnNew = document.querySelector(".btn-minus");

plusBtnNew.addEventListener("click", () => products.inCart++);
minusBtnNew.addEventListener("click", () => products.inCart--);` is what im currently using  and this is the error im getting Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null

Comment: `querySelector`, most likely. `querySelector` will return the first matching element in the DOM, while `getElementsByClassName` can return 0 or more elements. Since your cart only has 1 `.btn-plus` that you want to add an event handler to, I'd go with `querySelector('.btn-plus')`

Comment: And this is within the `quantityChange` method? If so we've got a timing problem most likely. Meaning `querySelector` is being called before the element actually has been created in the DOM

Comment: @AlexD yes this is the exact code `function quantityChange() {
  const plusBtnNew = document.querySelector(".btn-plus");
  const minusBtnNew = document.querySelector(".btn-minus");
  
  plusBtnNew.addEventListener("click", () => products.inCart++);
  minusBtnNew.addEventListener("click", () => products.inCart--);
}` there is no more error but the quantity is not being updated when i click on the buttons

Comment: So then the undefined/null error is solved. Based on your code, doing `products.inCart++` is going to increment your cart quantity as you want, but the HTML will not update unless you modify the html/text content of `.productQuantity`

Comment: @AlexD ah ok how would i do that?

Comment: I've edited the answer to include an example of how you might do this

Comment: @AlexD also how would i get these changes to persist to local storage? sorry im asking you too much

Comment: You would just need to update your localStorage key you're storing products in. I see you have "productsInCart", which I'm unsure if that is where you're storing this data, but you'd just need to do another `localStorage.setItem` to keep it in sync.

Comment: @AlexD when i  use the code that u suggested i would want the plus button changes the text to Nan do i need to parse it? also i am storing the as productsinCart

Comment: Make sure products.inCart exists, as `undefined++ === NaN`.

Comment: @AlexD  I tried parsing and am still getting NaN, products.inCart exists there were 8 in the cart when i tried it.

Comment: If you console.log/breakpoint in a debugger the value of `products.inCart` it displays 8? Because as long as a value is "coercible" to number (like "5", true, false, []) the `++` operation will produce a new number. Objects aren't coercible to number ({}, null, undefined) and will produce NaN.

Comment: @AlexD ah I see, I have tried Manas' solution and I am not having any NAN problems, I really appreciate your help and patience, I have only used JS for about a month and a half so I get confused and don't have the best understanding. Hopefully with more projects like this one I can get my first frontend web dev job!

Comment: No problem, glad it's solved. JavaScript is an old language that was not ever intended for the amount of use it gets nowadays. There are a lot of oddities in the language that can make it a bit difficult to learn. Good luck!